# getting No such PaymentMethod: 'tok_1IPAGM4unAps2Hiagy7H655b' error message when im trying to update laravel 5.8 to 7 with spark

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-spark

when I am going to update Laravel 5.8 to 7 and update dependencies like cashier, Laravel/spark-Aurelius . it's complete update but after registration with subcription it's shows an error  No such PaymentMethod: 'tok_1IPAGM4unAps2Hiagy7H655b' .

this comes back with an paymentMethod: tak_

but i get an exception like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLhPe.png

Answer (score 1):

tok_1IPAGM4unAps2Hiagy7H655b is a Token, not a Payment Method. If Laravel Cashier is expecting a Payment Method, you'll need to change your code to either:

- Change your backend code to create a Payment Method by passing in the token ID to `card[token]` (see https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card)
- Change your client-side code to create Payment Methods using the Stripe.js `createPaymentMethod` function instead of `createToken`. You can see the differences between the two here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration-synchronous#elements-step-1

Comment: sir actually when I'm degrade the version of Laravel 7 to 5.8 it's works totally fine without any error

Comment: Yes, and with that upgrade there were likely some breaking changes that requires you to change your integration. See https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#cards-and-payment-methods

Comment: yes sir I update the changes as you tell me but having same error.